# Vectors $v$ ,$w$ $∈$ $R^n$ whose length is one and are both orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, cross-product

What must $\lVert u \times v \rVert$ equal?

Pretty sure it is $1$ but just need reassurance.

Comment: is it vector product or tensor product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\|u\times v\|=|u||v|\sin (\pi/2)=1$